# Windows 7 /Eclipse watchpoint on file access

Tags: java, eclipse, filesystemwatcher, conditional-breakpoint

Is there a way in Eclipse [Helios] on Win 7 to watch for a file to be opened? Do I have to know where the app is going to do so, or is there a way to watch for a java.io object being created/something or other?

tia Rene

Comment: The sooner you realize that 'Eclipse' is not 'Java' - the better off you will be.  Note that the one answer on this thread so far, makes no mention of an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting breakpoints on the constructors of `FileInputStream` and/or `FileOutputStream` with conditions to check whether the filename provided matches your target filename (e.g. check the parameter on the constructors that take a filename, check the `File.getName()` on the constructors that take a `File`). Alternatively or in addition, you could set breakpoints on `File` constructors with a condition to check whether the specified filename is your target filename.

If your breakpoint trap trips, you can follow the stacktrace to see what methods are directly or indirectly access the file.